# why the UI did not change when I changed the store value

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am using vue 3 `"vue": "^3.2.29",` + typescript `"typescript": "^4.5.5",` to develop a google chrome extension. Using vuex `"vuex": "^4.0.2"` to manage the vue3 state.  when I received the result, I set the value using dispatch like this:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    async function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.msg === "something_completed") {
            let result = request.data.content
            await dispatch(
              'Trans/setUsername',
              result
              )
        }
    }
);
```

and this is the Trans store define:

```
const SET_USER_NAME = 'SET_USER_NAME'
const SET_RANDOM_IMG = 'SET_RANDOM_IMG'

export default {
  namespaced: true,

  state: {
    username: 'Tom',
    randomImg: 'https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/bulldog-french/n02108915_8258.jpg',
  },

  getters: {
    getUsername (state: { username: string }) {
      return state.username
    },
    getRandomImg (state: { randomImg: string }) {
      return state.randomImg
    },
  },

  mutations: {
    [SET_USER_NAME]: (state: { username: string }, username: string)=>{
      state.username = username
    },
    [SET_RANDOM_IMG]: (state: { randomImg: string }, randomImg: string)=>{
      state.randomImg = randomImg
    },
  },

  actions: {
    async setUsername ({dispatch, commit, getters}: any, data: unknown) {
        debugger
        commit('GET_USER_NAME', data)
    },
  },
}
```

and get user name in the vue 3 setup like this:

```
 let username = computed(()=>getters['Trans/getUsername'])
```

in the UI, bind the username like this:

```
    <span>{{username}}</span>
```

the UI could successfully render the default username `Tom`, but when I changed the username by dispath, the UI username did not changed. Am I missing something? what should I do to fix this problem? I am sure the setusername function works, and do the commit with the new value, but the UI just did not refresh.

Comment: Those two code snippets are completely different though. Can you give us a more concrete use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

access the store data in the UI like this way works:

```
    <span>{{$store.state.Trans.username}}</span>
```

it will update when store data changed.